# Error when trying to call function from deployed contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, error

Im trying to call a function in a contract called ReservoirV6_0_0, but the problem is that when I try to define an instance of the contract, like this: `ReservoirV6_0_0 reservoirContract = ReservoirV6_0_0(0xb35D22a4553Ab9d2b85e2A606CBAe55F844DF50c);`
I have the following error: [image]

Which is the first time Ive ever seen such error when trying to do this action.

Comment: Can you share the smart contract source code?

Comment: Yes of course, its deployed here https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xb35D22a4553Ab9d2b85e2A606CBAe55F844DF50c#code

Answer (score 1):

Address you are trying to cast in not payable here.
You can resolve the issue by making the address payable first before do the casting as follows

```
ReservoirV6_0_0 reservoirContract = ReservoirV6_0_0(payable(0xb35D22a4553Ab9d2b85e2A606CBAe55F844DF50c));
```

Comment: But why does it need to be payable ? Im just trying to use the instance of the contract like I always did